# FCM cloudmessaging.messages.create IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: rest, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are migrating from HTTP legacy API to HTTP V1 API for Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM). As per the documentation we have followed all steps by creating Service Account JSON file, get short lived Authentication token using the service account JSON file(with Java code) and then invoking Send Notification using FCM REST API.

Java code works perfectly fine and returning the access token. Same token is passed as "Bearer +accessToken" in Authorization section but we are getting "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED" error.

Below are the sample Request/Response parameter we are using to invoke REST API.

HTTP Post URL : https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/mt-middleware-****/messages:send

Authorization: Bearer "accessToken"
Request:
{
"message": {
"token": "********",//Device token
"notification": {
"body": "This is an FCM notification message!",
"title": "FCM Message"
}
}
}

Response:
{
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "Permission 'cloudmessaging.messages.create' denied on resource '//cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/mt-middleware-*****' (or it may not exist).",
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
"details": [
{
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
"reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED",
"domain": "cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com",
"metadata": {
"resource": "projects/mt-middleware-*****",
"permission": "cloudmessaging.messages.create"
}
}
]
}
}

We have tried to enable Firebase Admin role to the owner as well. But it did not help. Please guide if any other additional permission to be enabled in Firebase Console page?

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this issue before. I fixed this by creating a new service account at [FCM Service Accounts](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts).

After creating a new service account, Manage it's permission and assign it's role to **Owner** as seen in the image below:

[image]

Then after assigning it's role, go back to [FCM Service Accounts](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts), in the right hand side click the three dot menu and proceed to **Manage Keys**.

Once you are there you can generate a new key and save it as **JSON**. Replace your current **JSON** file and then try to initiate your application.

Hope this helps!